# Prove goal and contradictory assumption satisfiability?

Tags: logic, sequent-calculus

I’m studying for my first logic exam and have some questions regarding proof trees:

In the process of proving the satisfiability of a formula by a proof tree with sequent calculus, I need to close all the branches of the proof tree and can do so by closing it with a **goal assumption** (e.g.  A, B, C ⊢ B) or with a **contradictory assumption** (e.g. A, B, ¬B ⊢ C). What I’m not really sure about is:

1. Do goal assumptions and contradictory assumptions both indicate that a formula is satisfiable?
2. E.g. if I have a proof tree with 3 branches – 2 closed by a contradictory assumptions and 1 one by a goal assumption – does this proof the formula to be satisfiable?
3. And if I only have contradictory assumptions in my proof tree – is the formula satisfiable or not?

Thank's for any help in advance!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! You'll get more/better answers if you reference the precise formulation of the sequent system you're using (textbook, lecture notes, anything).

Comment: If **all** branches of the tree close with a contradiction, then the all tree is *unsatisfiable*, and thus also the formula in the root node.

Comment: If one branch is open, it defines a truth assignment that satisfies all formulas in the branch, and thus also the formula in the root.